# Adding items to ILIst as sourcecollection of a ListCollectionView

Tags: wpf, data-binding

According to the documentation, you have to implement INotifyCollectionChanged on the source collection of a ListCollectionView to propagate adding/removing of collections items.
So I don't understand how his is working:

```
        var parent = new Parent();
        parent.Childs = new List<Child>();
        parent.Childs.Add(new Child());
        parent.Childs.Add(new Child());
        parent.Childs.Add(new Child());
        var view = new ListCollectionView(parent.Childs);

        Assert.AreEqual(3, parent.Childs.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, view.Count);

        parent.Childs.Add(new Child());
        Assert.AreEqual(4, parent.Childs.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(4, view.Count);
```

Please, can anybody explain how this is working?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't this work? You are asserting after you have added the `Child` items. The `Count` property will always return the corrent number of items.

The reason why you need to implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface is for a *view* to be able to know when it should refresh the UI.

For example, if you add an item to a data-bound collection that you are displaying in a `ListView`, the source collection needs to raise the `CollectionChanged` event for the new item to automatically show up in the view.

Comment: What I did not expect is that the item is added to the view, while the source collection is an IList without an INotifyCollectionChanged event. How does the view knows that a item is added?

Comment: This is not a surprise. Why wouldn't it get added to the view/list? INotifyCollectionChanged only matters when the collection is data-bound.

Comment: For me it really is. Because the source list (ILIst) has no event to signal an added item to the view (ListCollectionView). Documentation says that the source list has to implement INotifyCollectionChanged for make this happening and that make sense to me. So my question is, how does the ListCollectionView knows that an item has added. Can I be sure that this is working always this way?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, the Count property will always return the current number of items each time you access it. INotifyCollectionChanged  is only required for the *UI* to be refreshed.

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about my point and question. After adding an item to the source collection (not implementing INotifyCollectionChanged) I don't expect that the item will be added to the ListCollectionView. But by surprise the item is added in the ListCollectionView, as shown in the green test above. How does the ListCollectionView know anything about the addition of a item to the source collection?

Comment: It has a reference the source collection internally and just return the number of items in the source collection from the Count property. How else would it work...?

Comment: Good point. But why should you then ever implement INotifyCollectionChanged or use an observablecollection. Only for performance?

Comment: Once again: For the *UI* to be refreshed when the source collection changes. In a unit test, it doesn't matter.

Comment: By the way, the item count cannot be used bij the ListCollectionView because there is no event coming from the IList. Now we both have the same question. Why is this working this way? And it really is....

Comment: You don't need an event...you access the Count property and then you get the current count. This is how the most basic imperative program works. A property is nothing more than a pair of get/set methods.